# More efficient way of implement this equation in pytorch (or Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm implementing the analytical form of this function

[image]

where k(x,y) is a RBF kernel `k(x,y) = exp(-||x-y||^2 / (2h))`

My function prototype is

```
def A(X, Y, grad_log_px，Kxy):
   pass
```

and `X`, `Y` are `NxD` matrix where `N` is batch size and `D` is a dimension. So `X` is a batch of `x` with size `N` in the above equation `grad_log_px` is some `NxD` matrix I've computed using `autograd`.

`Kxy` is `NxN` matrix where each entry `(i,j)` is the RBF kernel `K(X[i],Y[j])`

The challenge here is that in the above equation, `y` is just a vector with dimension `D`. I kind of want to pass into a batch of `y`. (So to pass matrix `Y` with `NxD` size)

The equation is fine using loop through the batch size but I'm having trouble to implement in a more neat way

here is my attempted loop solution:

```
def A(X, Y, grad_log_px，Kxy):
   res = []
   for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
       temp = 0
       for j in range(X.shape[0]):
           # first term of equation
           temp += grad_log_px[j].reshape(D,1)@(Kxy[j,i] * (X[i] - Y[j]) / h).reshape(1,D)
           temp += Kxy[j,i] * np.identity(D) - ((X[i] - Y[j]) / h).reshape(D,1)@(Kxy[j,i] * (X[i] - Y[j]) / h).reshape(1,D) # second term of equation
       temp /= X.shape[0]

        res.append(temp)
    return np.asarray(res) # return NxDxD array
```

In the equation: `grad_{x}` and `grad_{y}` both dimension `D`

Comment: Have you tried using numpy for implementing the equation?

Comment: @taurus05 does numpy has function that achieve this easier?

Comment: Numpy has a bunch of pre-defined set of functions. They are mostly written in c. So, you won't face any performance issues, if you use it.

Comment: Buuut if you want us `numpy` folks to be able to help we really need some more clues as to what the heck that equation is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Can you show your loopy solution?

Comment: @DanielF Thanks for reply; I've edit the post to include my loop solution provided that my gradient of kernel is correct

Comment: @ElleryL Could you explain how you arrive at the implementation for the second term? I'm missing at least a factor `1/h` and also a second term prop. to `-1/h**2` corresponding to the second derivative of the `exp`. Also could you clarify whether `grad_{x}` is actually `grad_{x_j}`, i.e. what are the dimensions of `grad_x` and `grad_y`?

Comment: @a_guest; hey thanks for reply; sorry for missing a factor in second equation; I've added it up. let me you if you have anything confused; `grad_y ` and `grad_x` both dimension D here

Comment: @a_guest; thanks for point out; I made mistake in second order of kernel. I've reedited the post

Comment: @ElleryL The dimensions are still not clear. In the text you say `y` is a D-vector but then it doesn't carry any subscript and in the code you seem to batch process `Y` which leds me to the assumption `y` is actually NxD. Also you report `grad_log_px` to be NxD but then, under the assumption that `grad <something>` denotes the outer product, the terms in the brackets are not compatible: NxD vs DxD (is `grad_x grad_y k(x, y)` DxD?). Anyway please add the *full* dimensions for each variable, i.e. 1xD instead of D, for all variables as well as the three terms in the brackets. Thanks.

Comment: @ElleryL Please also clarify what are outer and what are inner products in the equation. And please indicate to what the transposition refers to (i.e. only `log p` or `grad log p`) and what dimensions are transposed. Maybe you can also post the source of the equation to give it some context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that that I inferred all the dimensions of the various terms correctly here's a way to go about it. But first a summary of the dimensions (screenshot as it's easier to explain with math type setting; please verify if they are correct):

[image: Explanation]

Also note the double derivative of the second term which gives:

[image: Derivative]

where subscripts denote samples and superscripts denote features.

So we can create the two terms by using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) (similarly [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum)) and [array broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html):

```
grad_y_K = (X[:, None, :] - Y) / h * K[:, :, None]  # Shape: N_x, N_y, D
term_1 = np.einsum('ij,ikl->ikjl', grad_log_px, grad_y_K)  # Shape: N_x, N_y, D_x, D_y
term_2_h = np.einsum('ij,kl->ijkl', K, np.eye(D)) / h  # Shape: N_x, N_y, D_x, D_y
term_2_h2_xy = np.einsum('ijk,ijl->ijkl', grad_y_K, grad_y_K)  # Shape: N_x, N_y, D_x, D_y
term_2_h2 = K[:, :, None, None] * term_2_h2_xy / h**2  # Shape: N_x, N_y, D_x, D_y
term_2 = term_2_h - term_2_h2  # Shape: N_x, N_y, D_x, D_y
```

Then the result is given by:

```
(term_1 + term_2).sum(axis=0) / N  # Shape: N_y, D_x, D_y
```

Comment: I test it on small generated data; the results seems consistent; thanks so much